# TFS 2010 Auto Deployment for Web application

Tags: asp.net, deployment, webdeploy

I am new with TFS 2010 Auto Deployment. I have multiple Web Applications in one solution. Is there any simple way to deploy one web application only?

Comment: What do you mean by "*auto deployment*"? Should the web application be deployed automatically after a build?

Comment: Enrico, After Build gets created, i want to deploy that web app directly to a server.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use MSDeploy in combination with Team Build to achieve this. See this [blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/12/Auto-deployment-of-my-web-application-with-Team-Build-2010-to-add-Interactive-Testing.aspx) for more information.